# Div going off screen even when using vw units on my margins

Tags: html, css

I have the following div:

```
<body>
    <div class='centre'>
        <h1>Contact Me</h1>
        <a class="button" href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a class="button" href="About">About</a>
        <p>Use this form to contact me:</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I've used the following CSS on the body and div:

```
.centre{
    position: absolute;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 90vw;
    top: 50vw;
    left: 50vw;
    padding: 1vw;
    margin-top: 20vw;
    margin-bottom: 5vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px #000000;
    height: min-content;
}

body{
    background-color: #FA8BFF;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
```

As I add more and more content to the div so that the content doesn't fit on the screen, the height expands, but the top goes off screen despite specifying `margin-top: 20vw;`. I've noticed this only seems to happen whenever I resize the window to be very small, but the bottom margin always seems to remain. When I view the page on a large monitor, the top margin becomes disproportionately large and pushes my div content down very far, and the bottom margin still remains. I tried using percentage values as well, but they caused problems too.

What should I fix? Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, However from what you're describing it's a common issue with `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Answer (score 0):

I have set the margin in pixels.It works fine.Now you can add as many elements you want.

https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/NWGgYBX

```
.centre{
 position: absolute;
 height: 90px;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 90vw;
 top: 50px;
 left: 3.5vw;
 padding: 1vw;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 5vw;
 text-align: center;
 background: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px #000000;
 height: min-content;
 }

body{
 background-color: #FA8BFF;
 height:100vw;
 margin: 0;
 }
```